# How to show the common part of company candidates?

Tags: company-mode

Recently I have used company and I like it. But I feel prone to the mistake using the command `company-complete-common`. For example,
when I make company-mode enabled on emacs-lisp-mode,

1. I'm going to input the function "find-file". I typed "fin" one part of the function.
2. Many emacs-lisp functions "find-file","find-file--read-only",...,"finger" are included in company candidates.
3. Since the candidate popup often shows "find*" functions on display hiding the "finger" function, I execute `company-complete-common` by mistake. But the cursol is just moved down without completing common part.

So I want to know the common part before executing `company-complete-common`. Showing it like displaying continuing string with only one company candidate is ideal, I think. So is there the pacakge enabling it, or how to write the function to do so? I also want to know other ways to display the common part.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do this with the face `company-preview-common`. According to the documentation, this is the "Face used for the common part of the completion preview", but I have tried customizing it, and can't get it to work...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the foreground color of `company-preview-common` like
`(set-face-attribute 'company-preview-common nil :foreground "red")`, but it is
effective only when the candidate is sole and previewed. I want to preview the
common part among multiple candidates filtered by input string.

Comment: I posted this question to the company-mode page on github. I put the animated gif on that page and the question may be understandable, so refer to [this](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/564), too.